Study the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}\text{d}x$
Study the convergence of this improper integral, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}\text{d}x$$
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}\text{d}x = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}\text{d}x + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}\text{d}x = I_1 + I_2$$
$I$ converges iff both $I_1$ and $I_2$ converges.
I have a solution for the convergence of $I_1$, but no idea for $I_2$.
We have that, when $x \to 0^+$:
$$\frac{2\sin x- \sin2x}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})} = \frac{2\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})} \sim \frac{2x\cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^\alpha \cdot 3\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{3x^{\alpha - \frac{5}{2}}}$$
Since $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-\frac{5}{2}}}\text{d}x $
converges when $\alpha - \frac{5}{2} <1 \Leftrightarrow \alpha < \frac{7}{2}$, $I_1$ converges when $\alpha < \frac{7}{2}$.
Any help is much appreciated.

Let $f(x) = 2 \sin x - \sin 2x = 2 \sin x (1 - \cos x)$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})}$. $I_2 = \int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) dx$.
$f$ is periodical and $2 \pi$ is a period. $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is bounded by a constant for any $a \lt b$. For $\alpha \ge 0$, $g$ is non-negative monotonically decreasing on $[1, \infty)$. Therefore, according to Dirichlet's test for improper integrals, $I_2$ converges for $\alpha \ge 0$. Another more basic proof could be done using integration by parts.
Let's now study the convergence of $I_2$ for $\alpha \lt 0$. For any $k \in \mathbb N$, $f$ is a one sign map on $[k \pi, (k + 1) \pi]$, and $g$ is a positive increasing map for $x$ large enough. Let's say for $x \ge A \gt 1$. Hence for $k$ large enough $$\left\vert \int_{k \pi}^{(k + 1) \pi} f(x)g(x) dx \right\vert = \int_{k \pi}^{(k + 1) \pi} \lvert f(x) \rvert g(x) dx \ge g(A) \int_{k \pi}^{(k + 1) \pi} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx.$$
The right-hand side of those inequalities is a positive constant. $I_2$ is the sum of a series whose term is not converging to zero. Hence, $I_2$ is diverging for $\alpha \lt 0$.
Finally, $I$ converges if and only if $0 \le \alpha \lt \frac{7}{2}$.

Note that $g$ is increasing (when using the Dirichlet criterion).

I'm sure that for $\alpha\ge0$, $ g(x) = x^\alpha \ln(1+3\sqrt{x})
$ is increasing. And for $\alpha<0$ it is eventually decreasing.

@Gary Thanks. I understand now what you mean. And indeed, I need to speak of $1/g$. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Thanks for your answer, my professor have yet to mention Dirichlet's test for improper integral. Can you elaborate on the basic proof using integration by parts?

@sleeper161 You can integrate $f$ and differentiate $g$ in the integration by parts. You can then look when the remaining integral is absolutely convergent. Also, if you know the Dirichlet's test for series, deducing it for improper integrals is easy.

The integral $I_1$ is dealt with correctly.
As for $I_2$ one can first bound using
$
m\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log(1 + 3 \sqrt{x})}dx \leq I_2 \leq M \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log(1 + 3 \sqrt{x})}dx
$
where
$m = \min_{x\in[1,+\infty]}f(x)$
$M = \max_{x\in[1,+\infty]}f(x)$
$f(x) = 2\sin x(1-\cos x)$
The constants $m,M$ are both finite because $f(x)$ is bounded below and above (being just a trigonometric function).
By the comparison theorem for improper integrals and the previous inequality, $I_2$ converges if and only if
$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log(1 + 3 \sqrt{x})} $
does. For this last integral we compare with
$
\int_{1+\epsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha (\log x)^\beta}dx 
$
which is convergent for any $\beta$ whenever $\alpha>1$,  $\epsilon>0$.
For $x\to +\infty$
$
\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log(1 + 3 \sqrt{x})}  \sim \frac{2}{x^\alpha \log(x)} 
$
Then $I$ is convergent if and only if $1 < \alpha < \frac{7}{2}$.

You proved absolute convergence, when $\alpha<1$ you can't conclude $I_2$ diverges

@gdvdv Study the convergence... means to say when it is convergent and when it is divergent depending on the values of $\alpha$.

I deleted my comment by mistake sorry where I said "It only asked about the convergence". Anyways, this is a bit of unnecessary semantic and I'll update the answer.

Convergence does not (usually) mean absolute convergence

Indeed convergence and absolute convergence are not equivalent...

Even after the edit, this approach does not provide a full answer

I am not very familiar with answering questions here and I apologize for that. I don't know what exactly qualifies as "full answer". Mathematically speaking, the regions of convergence (according to @mathcounterexamples.net definition) have been identified and the proof is rigorous. In case it's a matter of presentation and/or aesthetic canon I'd like to know. Could you indicate the relevant reference on this website where the qualifier "full", referred to an answer, is explained?

@gdvdv By full I meant complete. See my first comment. Your solution is incomplete, since you only proved absolute convergence and you have to deal with conditional convergence for $\alpha <1$. Moreover, you have to ping a user (using @), otherwise there'll be no notification

@SineoftheTime right! Yes, in the end I think the correct approach is using the Dirichelet test as mentioned in the other answer. Tricky oscillating part...

Ok, so meaybe it's better if you specify that you've analized absolute convergence
